# Equivalent of loginViewShowingLoggedInUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to migrate my app from Facebook SDK 3.4 to 4.x. 
I used the following import

```
   #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
   #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
   #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h>
```

I used to have two methods

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
```

I can't find these methods in 4.x SDK.

I can see FBLoginView changed to FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate. But what is the equivalent of above two methods. I tried looking at Facebook iOS samples but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method called `loginButton:didCompleteWithResult:error:` defined in [FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate) :

```
- (void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult: (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
               error: (NSError *)error;
```

Source : [Facebook SDK Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#custom-login-button)

**Note :** The above delegate is only for a login button, i.e. the delegate will be called only when the user performs a login using the login button. So this delegate will not get called every time the app is launched like `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:` used to do.

You have to use [FBSDKLoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/) to check if user is aleady logged in :

> `FBSDKLoginManager` works directly with `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` and sets the `currentAccessToken` upon successful authorizations (or sets `nil` in case of logOut).
>
> You should check `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` before calling logIn* to see if there is a cached token available (typically in your `viewDidLoad`).

As for retrieving user info, the new SDK does not automatically fetch user info. inside you login success handler, you have to make a graph request :

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setValue:@"id,name,email,gender" forKey:@"fields"];
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSString *userID = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID];
         NSString *userName = [result valueForKey:@"name"];
         NSString *emailid=[result valueForKey:@"email"];
         NSString *gender=[result valueForKey:@"gender"];
         NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID]];
     }
     else{
         NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
     }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this method be called when a user has already logged in and it is showing the current logged in user.

Comment: This method will not be called if when you launch the app and the user is already logged in. I will update answer

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.